# Visual Studio 2017 can not connected to MAC Agent

Tags: macos, visual-studio, ssh, mono, xamarin-studio

i try to connect vs2017 (Xamarin 4.3) to MAC Agent(El Capitan) in Virtual Machine (VMWare). I have see every link in internet and not working anything

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/#knownissues

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

The log show me the next

```
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService.<StartBrokerAsync>d__87.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   en Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService.<ConnectAsync>d__67.MoveNext()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.DisconnectedState|Error|0|No se pudo conectar con Mac-Admin.local.. Vuelva a intentarlo.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Transición de estado del servidor de SshConnectingState a DisconnectedState en Mac-Admin.local. (10.10.0.82)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Desconectado del equipo Mac Mac-Admin.local. (10.10.0.82)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Transición de estado del servidor de DisconnectedState a SshConnectingState en Mac-Admin.local. (10.10.0.82)
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService|Information|0|Iniciando la conexión con Mac 10.10.0.82...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService|Information|0|Iniciando el agente 4.3.0.784 en el puerto 50656...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommands|Error|0|No se encuentra una instalación Mono en el equipo Mac
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommands|Error|0|Ubicaciones sondeadas para Mono en el equipo Mac: /usr/bin/mono64, /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono64
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.DisconnectedState|Error|0|La inicialización del agente intermediario superó el tiempo de espera de 60000 milisegundos sin recibir confirmación del agente intermediario.
System.TimeoutException: La inicialización del agente intermediario superó el tiempo de espera de 60000 milisegundos sin recibir confirmación del agente intermediario.
   en Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.BrokerCommands.<StartBrokerAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService.<StartBrokerAsync>d__87.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   en Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService.<ConnectAsync>d__67.MoveNext()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.DisconnectedState|Error|0|No se pudo conectar con Mac-Admin.local.. Vuelva a intentarlo.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Transición de estado del servidor de SshConnectingState a DisconnectedState en Mac-Admin.local. (10.10.0.82)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Desconectado del equipo Mac Mac-Admin.local. (10.10.0.82)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Transición de estado del servidor de DisconnectedState a SshConnectingState en Mac-Admin.local. (10.10.0.82)
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Warning|0|No se pudo ejecutar "grep "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCs6D+43Z2dxNsvYZ+NfM73iQxye9C/sn30tjOlDDl1Z/tIzTG8Du4X6gYCad8M+CGQCGdsW1zBD+Cqx9yhEa0D1VZKoRXcJhYWcsv2pS8wmwkc/+7zRcUhFDIxrgxd+2lWu8CUN+70KAuroctEas9/Thasoo3N0lAOCQHu6YqCHRw6iJ7tDOgdYSMKrByZTErd2yo3CJ3i7F07brkT5EMU18VUJcQnfkMRxf5k0pVs0wtlMYF/m720MFRCTQGrsx+4ZGiwRZIyfRp7gmZTv+KZiM1KSfnkaFSxUBZp6iFbW7lJVUOfAXjovorKqE/YQJa04vNcijUtaAsJgZsiQ5i3 admin@mac-admin.segurmatica.cu" /Users/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys": ExitStatus = 1
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService|Information|0|Iniciando la conexión con Mac 10.10.0.82...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService|Information|0|Iniciando el agente 4.3.0.784 en el puerto 56425...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommands|Error|0|No se encuentra una instalación Mono en el equipo Mac
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommands|Error|0|Ubicaciones sondeadas para Mono en el equipo Mac: /usr/bin/mono64, /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono64
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.State.DisconnectedState|Error|0|La inicialización del agente intermediario superó el tiempo de espera de 60000 milisegundos sin recibir confirmación del agente intermediario.
System.TimeoutException: La inicialización del agente intermediario superó el tiempo de espera de 60000 milisegundos sin recibir confirmación del agente intermediario.
   en Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.BrokerCommands.<StartBrokerAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en X
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in the connection between host and agent. I tried to set network adaptor as "bridge" but issue wasn't resolved. Try this few steps:

1. Open mac os, install latest xcode, ios sdk, xamarin and enable remote login on mac os;
2. Open windows, Go to VMWare Workstation settings -> Network Adapter -> Custom: Specific virtual network -> Select VMnet8(NAT);
3. Reboot vm;
4. When reboot will have finished go to Visual Studio 2017 -> Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> iOS Settings -> Find Xamarin Mac Agent. Here you will find _ssh connection. Open it and write mac os user credentials.

After that connection was successfully established